# Error: The string is missing the terminator:

Tags: powershell

```
#Write-Host "Hello, World!"
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$str = $args

$str1 = $str.Replace(""", "")
$array1 = $str1.split(",")
$array_length = $array1.Length
$user_id = $array1[0]
$unremoved_Ad = @($array_length - 1)

for($i = 1; $i -lt $array_length; $i++) {
    Write-Host "$($user_id) - $($array1[$i])"

    try {
        #Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity $array[$i] -Member $user_id -Confirm:$false
    } catch {
        $unremoved_Ad = $unremoved_Ad + $array[$i]

        if($i -ne ($array_length - 1)) {
            $unremoved_Ad = $unremoved_Ad
        }
    }
}
Write-Host $unremoved_Ad
```

Hi I am new to Powershell and I am trying to do just a basic thing above. However, I get an error: `The string is missing terminator:` .

Updating the code. Looks like there is a major goof up in `Write-Host` immediately after `for` loop.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue is with the brackets and extra dot.

**Instead of your code,**
**Do This:**

```
#Write-Host "Hello, World!"
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$str = $args

$str1 = $str.Replace('"', "")
$array1 = $str1.split(",")
$array_length = $array1.Length
$user_id = $array1[0]
$unremoved_Ad = @($array_length - 1)


for($i = 1; $i -lt $array_length; $i++) {
    Write-Host "$($user_id) - $($array1[$i])"

    try {
        #Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity $array[$i] -Member $user_id -Confirm:$false
    } catch {
        $unremoved_Ad = $unremoved_Ad + $array[$i]

        if($i -ne ($array_length - 1)) 
        {
            $unremoved_Ad = $unremoved_Ad
        }
    }
}                
Write-Host $unremoved_Ad
```

Comment: @PreetiMaurya Here you go . Its working now. Accept the answer if you got it :)

Comment: I have updated the answer @PreetiMaurya according to your need now. The issue is with quotes only. The quote started but it was not having any end since everywhere you are using double quotes. You should use single quote also to avoid this discrepancy.